# Beamer: vertically align subsections in beamercolorbox inside of a header

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

I want to customize my beamer presentation. Unfortunately, I have a problem with the header. I changed the fonts (here I used standard fonts so you can try it out) which caused a part of the header content to be occluded by the frame title (there just wasn't enough space for the content typeset using new fonts). So, I decided to make the header more responsive to the provided content. I made its height dependent on the number of sections and the font used to typeset section title (I know the code isn't great but I do not know TeX/LaTeX well).

All works fine if I've got an equal number of sections and subsections. If there are fewer subsections than sections, I would like the subsections to be centered or aligned to the top of their box. Unfortunately, they get aligned to the bottom of their box which looks strange (see the screen shots). Do you have any ideas on how to make it right?
[image: Optimal situation]

[image: Problematic situation]

Below I provide the MWE, feel free to rewrite it completely if needed.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\useinnertheme{rounded}

% =================================================== %
% CUSTOMIZATIONS
% =================================================== %
\definecolor{MyShade1}{RGB}{240, 240, 240}
\definecolor{MyShade2}{RGB}{225, 225, 225}
\definecolor{Fg}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{Bg}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=MyShade1,fg=Fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=MyShade2,fg=Fg}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=Fg,bg=Bg}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\npmedium{Roboto Medium}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\npmedium, size*={6pt}{7pt}}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{family=\npmedium, size*={6pt}{7pt}}
\setbeamerfont{headline highlight}{family=\npmedium, size*={6pt}{7pt}}

% MY HEADER => PROBLEMATIC PART - START

\makeatletter

\newlength{\@myheight}%  height of 1 section title
\setlength{\@myheight}{1em}%
\newlength{\@pusher}%  push down frame title (for some reason it occludes the header)
\setlength{\@pusher}{0.5mm}%
\newcount\@secnum%  max number of sections in the presentation
\@secnum=4%
\multiply\@myheight by\@secnum%
\advance\@myheight by -0.5em%

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
    \leavevmode%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@myheight]{section in head/foot}%
        \insertsectionnavigation{0.5\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=\@myheight]{subsection in head/foot}%
        \insertsubsectionnavigation{0.5\paperwidth}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vskip + \@pusher}{}

\makeatother

% MY HEADER => PROBLEMATIC PART - END

\title{MWE}
\author{Tester}
\institute{n/a}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{SubSection 1.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.1}
    SubSection 1.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.2}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.2}
    SubSection 1.2
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.3}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.3}
    SubSection 1.3
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.4}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.4}
    SubSection 1.4
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{SubSection 2.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 2.1}
    SubSection 2.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 2.2}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 2.2}
    SubSection 2.2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{SubSection 3.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 3.1}
    SubSection 3.1
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\subsection{SubSection 4.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 4.1}
    SubSection 4.1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT: Unresponsive header in base theme (= original problem)**

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\useinnertheme{rounded}

% =================================================== %
% CUSTOMIZATIONS
% =================================================== %
\definecolor{MyShade1}{RGB}{240, 240, 240}
\definecolor{MyShade2}{RGB}{225, 225, 225}
\definecolor{Fg}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{Bg}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=MyShade1,fg=Fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=MyShade2,fg=Fg}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=Fg,bg=Bg}

% Font changes producing the occlusion effect
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\npregular{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\npmedium{Roboto Medium}
\newfontfamily\npblack{Roboto Black}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\npmedium, size*={8pt}{9pt}}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{family=\npmedium, size*={8pt}{9pt}}
\setbeamerfont{headline highlight}{family=\npmedium, size*={8pt}{9pt}}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\npregular, size*={11pt}{13pt}}
\setbeamerfont{frametext}{family=\npregular, size*={11pt}{13pt}}

% % Baseline changes producing the occlusion effect
% \setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size*={6pt}{9pt}}
% \setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size*={6pt}{9pt}}
% \setbeamerfont{headline highlight}{size*={6pt}{9pt}}
% % Default font size changes producing the occlusion effect
% \setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size*={8pt}{8pt}}
% \setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size*={8pt}{8pt}}
% \setbeamerfont{headline highlight}{size*={8pt}{8pt}}

\title[MWE and Me]{MWE}
\author{Tester}
\institute{n/a}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{SubSection 1.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.1}
    SubSection 1.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.2}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.2}
    SubSection 1.2
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.3}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.3}
    SubSection 1.3
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.4}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.4}
    SubSection 1.4
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{SubSection 2.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 2.1}
    SubSection 2.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 2.2}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 2.2}
    SubSection 2.2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{SubSection 3.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 3.1}
    SubSection 3.1
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\subsection{SubSection 4.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 4.1}
    SubSection 4.1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Any change of font (usage of a taller/ticker font, bigger size or baseline of default font => try different commented alternatives) produces the occlusion effect as the header is unresponsive. Find some examples below.

Different font:
[image]
[image]

Bigger baseline:
[image]
[image]

Larger font (standard baseline):
[image]
[image]

Comment: This sounds very much like an xy problem. Instead of reinventing the wheel, use the split headline and increase the value of 1.825ex in l. 55 to whatever your font needs. (there you can also see how to centre the subsections)

Comment: Can you edit your question to reproduce your original problem with the too tall font?

Comment: Sorry for the delay - hectic days at work. I edited the question as you asked for. Of course the code you suggested solves my problem. Will you write the answer to the question or I should do so?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you very much for the help. You are the best! :)

Comment: The underlying problem was indeed much easier to solve than the vertical alignment of your custom headline :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since commit https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/5e32665a0382d91e3ebddc5080c717f962a8e0fa (which should be included in beamer versions 3.71 or newer), beamer automatically takes into account the fontsize of the `section in head/foot` font when creating the headline.

So without any manual intervention, your example

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass[final]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}

\useinnertheme{rounded}

% =================================================== %
% CUSTOMIZATIONS
% =================================================== %
\definecolor{MyShade1}{RGB}{240, 240, 240}
\definecolor{MyShade2}{RGB}{225, 225, 225}
\definecolor{Fg}{RGB}{0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{Bg}{RGB}{255, 255, 255}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{bg=MyShade1,fg=Fg}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{bg=MyShade2,fg=Fg}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=Fg,bg=Bg}

% Font changes producing the occlusion effect
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\npregular{Roboto}
\newfontfamily\npmedium{Roboto Medium}
\newfontfamily\npblack{Roboto Black}
\setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{family=\npmedium, size*={8pt}{9pt}}
\setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{family=\npmedium, size*={8pt}{9pt}}
\setbeamerfont{headline highlight}{family=\npmedium, size*={8pt}{9pt}}
\setbeamerfont{normal text}{family=\npregular, size*={11pt}{13pt}}
\setbeamerfont{frametext}{family=\npregular, size*={11pt}{13pt}}

 % Baseline changes producing the occlusion effect
% \setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size*={6pt}{9pt}}
% \setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size*={6pt}{9pt}}
% \setbeamerfont{headline highlight}{size*={6pt}{9pt}}
% % Default font size changes producing the occlusion effect
 \setbeamerfont{section in head/foot}{size*={8pt}{8pt}}
 \setbeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}{size*={8pt}{8pt}}
 \setbeamerfont{headline highlight}{size*={8pt}{8pt}}

\title[MWE and Me]{MWE}
\author{Tester}
\institute{n/a}
\date{\today}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{SubSection 1.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.1}
    SubSection 1.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.2}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.2}
    SubSection 1.2
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.3}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.3}
    SubSection 1.3
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 1.4}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 1.4}
    SubSection 1.4
\end{frame}

\section{Section 2}
\subsection{SubSection 2.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 2.1}
    SubSection 2.1
\end{frame}

\subsection{SubSection 2.2}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 2.2}
    SubSection 2.2
\end{frame}

\section{Section 3}
\subsection{SubSection 3.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 3.1}
    SubSection 3.1
\end{frame}

\section{Section 4}
\subsection{SubSection 4.1}
\begin{frame}{SubSection 4.1}
    SubSection 4.1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

will produce the following result:

[image]